# Getting Exc_Bad_access in AVAssetReader

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avasset, avassetreader

I am getting Exc_bad_Access exception while reading a file with AVAssetReader .
The File is located in document directory and is in m4a format. Here is the code i am using. Not able to figure out where m getting it wrong:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"My_Recording2.m4a"];

NSURL *newURL=[NSURL URLWithString:filepath];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:newURL.absoluteString])
{
    NSLog(@"File exists");
}

AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:newURL options:nil];
NSError *assetError;

if(asset)
    NSLog(@"all ok");

self.assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:asset error:&assetError];
```

I am getting the exception at last line i.e.

```
self.assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:asset error:&assetError];
```

Comment: use AVAsset assetWithURL: just to try maybe AVURLAsset is for web content. Is your assetReader Property set to strong?

Comment: yes assetReader Property is strong one. i tried using assetWithURL still same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your [NSURL URLWithString:filepath] is not right.
Can you try with fileURLWithPath method. Hopefully that will solve your issue.

Comment: after this i am using AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:newURL options:nil];
NSError *assetError;
if(audioAsset)
    NSLog(@"all ok");

NSLog(@" array is %@",audioAsset.tracks); to get track but track array is empty if i log can you tell me why ?

Comment: If url is correct (check first its correct) then as documentation says sometimes you have to make sure if tracks loaded. Use loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler: ^{  //for that.